# No config named ... error when running ipsec up <conn name>

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I am getting the 'no config named ...' error like others have posted. I have auto=add in my etc/ipsec.conf file as I read in one post. I have followed everything which I have read online to no avail. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 and the latest strongswan. Let me know what information I need to provide to get some help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently your config is not loaded. Maybe there is a syntax error (check the log, post that and the complete config if you can't figure it out yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, went back and looked at the logs in /var/log and found that it was having an issue with loading aes256. Removed that from the ipsec.conf file, restart and viola! Now have to figure out why it doesn't like aes256?